# How do I get the element Datetime using selenium without using XPath?

Tags: python, selenium

how do i find that class datetime element using selenium.
not xpath please as that dont work on headless chrome and i do not want to see the browser showing up when i am coding this to run in background every hr.

i've tried this

```
pp = p.find_element_by_class_name('line-height-3')
print(pp.get_attribute('datetime'))
```

results

```
none
```

[image]

i've figured it out

```
    Announcement = driver.find_element_by_class_name('discussion.subscribed')
if Announcement.is_displayed():
    Announcement_id    = Announcement.get_attribute('data-discussionid')
    Announcement_title = Announcement.find_element_by_class_name('w-100.h-100.d-block').get_attribute('title')
    TIME = Announcement.find_element_by_id('time-created-'+str(Announcement_id))
    Time = TIME.get_attribute('datetime')
```

so i just putting it out incase anyone else came by such problem.
The reason why I am not using xpath is that whenever it runs in headless mode
i get `nosuch`error but in normal mode. it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your id is dynamic so you can not use it. You can use cssSelector if xpath is not nice for you.
See more on https://www.browserstack.com/guide/css-selectors-in-selenium

I do not have more HTML of your page, but you can try with:
time[datatimeformat='part that is hard to see on your picture']

Comment: i've gotten the answer. i used  
'    Announcement = driver.find_element_by_class_name('discussion.subscribed')
    if Announcement.is_displayed():
        Announcement_id    = Announcement.get_attribute('data-discussionid')
        Announcement_title = Announcement.find_element_by_class_name('w-100.h-100.d-block').get_attribute('title')
        TIME = Announcement.find_element_by_id('time-created-'+str(Announcement_id))
        Time = TIME.get_attribute('datetime')' and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Try getting it by id.

```
pp = p.find_element_by_id('time-created-82672')
print(pp.get_attribute('datetime'))
```

Comment: I've tried that but whenever the page refresh the -82672 changes

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS selector

```
pp = p.find_element_by_css('div.author-info time')
print(pp.get_attribute('datetime'))
```

If you will change your mind there xpath :)

```
.//div[contains(@class, 'author-info')]//time
```

Comment: lol .. xpath gives me alot of errors when using headless so i just go with the other find element methods.

Comment: i'd copy the xpath from the html inspect script to where i'd want it to be. so possibly

Comment: Browser generate terrible xpath. If site use autogenerated  classes, id, etc. this xpath can be useless